# Yii2 grid data from multiple tables (selecting records of multiple tables)

Tags: mysql, gridview, yii2

I have a grid view where I need to show data of more than a table, each record in a row (Not relations).
Thus, a group of grid rows may come from table one, another group of rows from table two, ect...

For example, I need to select from tbl1 rows (suppose r1 to r10), and from table tbl2, rows (suppose r11 to r20) r1 to r10 and r11 to r20 may have a lot of common id's (because from different tables). And I want to show all these records in a single grid view, with search and actions enabled.

I have made an attempt to get data in arrayDataProvider, and it worked perfect.
The problems I am trying to fix are two:
1. Enabling the searchModel in the grid. (For that, I have also get all data in the search model in arrayDataProvider, but still need to enable search).
2. I need to know which record is selected for(view, update, or delete) and take action based on the selection, because the same id may exist in the grid multiple times, each from a table.

Comment: if you can .. you should updated  your question and add a  proper sample  .. (your question is not clear to me)

Comment: Thank u for commenting. Edited, Is it clear now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Enable Search:
1. I have used all search models to return arrays based on filtering queries.
2. I have used a basic search model that includes common attributes between all tables, it calls functions from other search models to get array from them, then it concatenates all these arrays and returns them as an array data provider.
3. Needed some attention when dealing with parameters in search models, because they are using the same model as the basic, they have more fields.

When I treat id's and acyions on rows, I will post the method.
If any one having the same issue, and need help, I will be :-)